# From BinaryExpression to Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Suppose I have something like

```
Expression<Func<SomeType, DateTime>> left = x => x.SomeDateProperty;
Expression<Func<SomeType, DateTime>> right = x => dateTimeConstant;
var binaryExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> predicate = 
                          x => x.SomeDateProperty> dateTimeConstant;
```

1) How can I replace the right hand of the assignment of the last line with something that uses the `binaryExpression` instead? `var predicate = x => binaryExpression;` doesn't work.

2) The `right` is always a constant, not necessarily DateTime.Now. Could it be of some simpler `Expression` type? For instance, it doesn't depend on SomeType, it is just a constant.

3) If I have the `GreaterThan` as a `string`, is there a way to get from this string to the method with the same name in `Expression`? In general, if the name of the comparison method is given as a `string`, how can I go from the string to actually calling the method with the same name on the `Expression` class?

It has to work with LINQ to Entities, if it matters.

Comment: You can change expression trees using the ExpressionVisitor class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1 and 2: You need to build the expression tree manually to do this, the compiler cannot help because it only constructs ready-made expressions that represent functions *in their entirety*. That's not useful when you want to build functions piece by piece.

Here's one straightforward way to build the expression you want:

```
var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeType));
var left = Expression.Property(argument, "SomeDateProperty");
var right = Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now);

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeType, bool>>(
    Expression.GreaterThan(left, right),
    new[] { argument }
);
```

You can take this for a test drive with

```
var param = new SomeType { 
    SomeDateProperty = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(-1))
};

Console.WriteLine(predicate.Compile()(param)); // "False"
```

3: Since in all likelihood the number of possible choices for your binary predicate will be quite small, you could do this with a dictionary:

```
var wordToExpression = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression>>
{
    { "GreaterThan", Expression.GreaterThan },
    // etc
};
```

Then, instead of hardcoding `Expression.GreaterThan` in the first snippet you would do something like `wordToExpression["GreaterThan"](left, right)`.

Of course this can also be done the standard way with reflection.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `GreaterThan`, you need to specify the expression *bodies*, not the lambda itself. Unfortunately, there is a complication: the `x` in the two expressions *is not the same*.

In this **particular** case, you could just about get away with this, because the second expression *does not use `x`*

So; your "1" and "2" should be answered by:

```
var binaryExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(left.Body, right.Body);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeType, bool>>(binaryExpression,
        left.Parameters);
```

However, to handle this in the general case, you must *rewrite* on of the expressions, to fix-up the parameters:

```
var binaryExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(left.Body,
    new SwapVisitor(right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]).Visit(right.Body));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeType, bool>>(binaryExpression,
    left.Parameters);
```

with:

```
public class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

For your "3"; there is nothing inbuilt for that; you could use reflection, though:

```
string method = "GreaterThan";

var op = typeof(Expression).GetMethod(method,
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
    null, new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(Expression) }, null);

var rightBody = new SwapVisitor(right.Parameters[0],
     left.Parameters[0]).Visit(right.Body);
var exp = (Expression)op.Invoke(null, new object[] { left.Body, rightBody });

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeType, bool>>(exp, left.Parameters);
```