# Entity Framework, variable criteria runs much more slowly

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities

The following runs very quickly <0.3s, with a constant in the predicate condition

```
IQueryable<fn_GetDocumentsForContact_Result> _queriable;
var zeus = new Zeus();
var UoW = new UnitOfWork(zeus);
var sp = new StoredProcedureService(zeus);

int _userId = 183494;
int totalRecords = 0;
int doctype = 2;

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<fn_GetDocumentsForContact_Result>();

predicate = predicate.And(x=>x.Type == 2);

IQueryable<fn_GetDocumentsForContact_Result> documents = 
    sp.fn_GetDocumentsForContact(183494)
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(predicate);

_queriable = documents;

_queriable.Count().Dump();
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @ctcIDnumber Int = 183494
DECLARE @p__linq__0 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[fn_GetDocumentsForContact](@ctcIDnumber) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Type] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

If I change:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x=>x.Type == 2);
```

To

```
predicate = predicate.And(x=>x.Type == doctype);
```

The same SQL is still generated, however the db connection times out.

The SQL runs very quickly through `SSMS`, I've tried clearing the query cache and running the SQL through `sp_executeSQL`, in both scenarios the query executes in well under 1 second. Removing the `LinqKit` predicate builder makes no difference either.

My initial instinct would have been parameter sniffing, however, the query in question only calls an `Inline TVF` and my understanding is that PS only applies to compiled sprocs.

Comment: My first 'guess' for any such related question is Parameter Sniffing. And no, it's *not* only with procs :} Try running the same SQL with and without parameters. Does it follow the same performance / speed indicated by the program?

Comment: If you mean running the SQL query with the values inlined, they yes it performs well. I can't make the query run slowly in SSMS whichever way I try it. Since the same SQL is generated with static and variable params, why should one suffer sniffing? - Though clearly it's happening

Comment: I suspect it comes down to a cached query plan that is reused. When there are variables the query plans are the same - even though they get different values. The first run after clearing the query cache will likely be fast (and this is something to try), even with the form that uses variables. The 'ick' is the cached plan was generated with some data in mind - and well, if the multiplicties are off it'll tank.

Comment: Ordering before the count sorts the problem, though I can't say I'm exactly sure why - so I don't know if it's going to blow up...

Comment: (I suppose it isn't "the same" as PS, but it comes down to using a non-ideal plan for the current variable values. YMMV with 'cleverly modified queries' - been there, done that, limited success.)

Comment: One thing might be to [manually] create an Expr using a Constant.. which would effectively bypass the cache (or "dirty the cache", depending on view).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last comment

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16808461/2864740 - by manually building the `Expression.Equals(prop, Expression.Constant)` it bypasses EF (or whatever LINQ provider) from using parameters in the query. If indeed it *is* the parameters and reused query plans that are problematic..

Comment: @user2864740, that works, if you post an answer I'll accept - I've been on holiday so apologies for my tardy response

Comment: @SWa, does the constant expression worked? Does it speed up your query time (ie. no more DB timed out)?