# Entity Framework - Using Linq to Invoke Field Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, invoke

I am using net 4.5, C# and Entity Framework. I want to be able to invoke a Field at runtime for a linq query.

```
using var( context = new SomeDataEntities())
{
    var abc = from b in context.someTable
              where b.SomeField == 1
              select b.AnotherField;
}
```

However I am want to invoke b.SomeField based on a input string parameter.
my current code is

```
using var( context = new SomeDataEntities())
{
    var abc = from b in context.someTable
              where b.GetType().GetProperty("SomeField").GetValue(b, null).ToString() == "test"
              select b.AnotherField;
}
```

Comment: note - this is just a basic example, I will be executing a more complex query.

Comment: You can't, that can't be translated into a Transact sql query. Your only other option is to retrieve the entire content into memory and then execute the where clause with reflection. You can also use libraries that support dynamic sql generation using strings for properties. See [dynamic linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Comment: good call, I am going to explore creating a dynamic query using Expression

Comment: Or you can use Dynamic Linq.  See https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library, https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/, and https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki.  Not sure if it's completely EF compliant, though.

Comment: You should also have a look at Joseph Albahari's Predicate Builder at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create a where clause, the best way to do this is the method chaining instead of the linq format.  For instance:

```
using (var context = new SomeDataEntities())
{
     var query = context.Set<SomeTable>();
     if (field1.HasValue)
     {
          query = query.Where(e => e.Field1 == field1.Value);
     }

     if (field2.HasValue)
     {
          query = query.Where(e => e.Field2 == field2.Value);
     }    

     var abc = query.Select(b => b.AnotherField);
}
```

If you have a lot of fields or an unknown number, SQL generation might be your best strategy and can be accessed with the DbContext.Database.SqlQuery() methods.

Comment: With your example, how would I invoke the field? or call by name? cause here it appears it needs to be defined. (field1 or field2).

Comment: How many fields do you have?  With the method chaining, you would have to build it up for each value.  If you need it to be dynamic, you can probably build up the entry into the Where() clause.

Comment: The type for the Where clause is Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>>.  You could build it starting with Expression.Equal(,): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.equal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808121/from-binaryexpression-to-expressionfunct-bool